# Пиксельный текст на картинке

Tags: php

Как вывести в PHP пиксельный текст на картинке, но чтобы он выводился именно как пиксельный и никак не трансформировался? Для примера на первой картинке как должно быть, а на второй как получается сделать.

[image]

[image]

Comment: какой библиотекой пользуетесь?

Comment: GD библиотекой

Comment: У меня была похожая проблема: на локальном сервере картинка с пиксельным шрифтом генерировалась отлично, без смазываний, а на хостинге - все смазывалось. Вообщем после долгих матов и танцев случайно нашлось решение - размер шрифта выставить не целым числом, на пару десятых меньше. В итоге на всех серверах все отлично работало)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идем по [ссылке](http://daak.ru/) и скачиваем шрифт! Далее идем по [ссылке](http://mysitez.km.ua/Programming/?graphfunc2) и узнаем как шрифт можно задействовать на создавемом изображенни!

Comment: Вторая ссылка оказалась полезной.
Из нее подчерпнул программу PHP Font Editor, с помощью которой и сделаю пиксельный шрифт. Благонужны только цифры.

Answer (score 1):

Отрицательный индекс цвета выключает антиалиасинг (смягчение видимых границ за счёт легкого размытия). Если цвет черный, придётся сделать его хотя бы (1,1,1), как пишут [тут](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php#91061).

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно выводить только цифры, то можно ограничиться выводом картинок цифр, а не текста.

Comment: На крайний случай оставил этот вариант.